# how do you fix a get_node: node not found "pivot" in godot

Tags: game-physics, godot

im trying to make a character in godot with the default movement script and am getting a error whenever turn it on.

```
E 0:00:01.914   get_node: (Node not found: "Pivot" (relative to "/root/world/KinematicBody").)
  <C++ Error>   Method failed. Returning: nullptr
  <C++ Source>  scene/main/node.cpp:1465 @ get_node()
  <Stack Trace> KinematicBody.gd:25 @ _physics_process()
```

this is the code i have

```
extends KinematicBody

# How fast the player moves in meters per second.
export var speed = 14
# The downward acceleration when in the air, in meters per second squared.
export var fall_acceleration = 75

var velocity = Vector3.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = Vector3.ZERO

    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        direction.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        direction.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_back"):
        direction.z += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
        direction.z -= 1

    if direction != Vector3.ZERO:
        direction = direction.normalized()
        $Pivot.look_at(translation + direction, Vector3.UP)

    velocity.x = direction.x * speed
    velocity.z = direction.z * speed
    velocity.y -= fall_acceleration * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

i am using godot 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what is the problem: Your Scene tree does not include a Node with the name "Pivot".

$Pivot is an alternative way of writing get_node("Pivot"), which searches a node at the current position with this name. If it is not there you run into this error.

I don't know what you mean with "default" movement script, but I am assuming you copying this code from somewhere. Look at the tree of the scene you copied the script from and you should see the Pivot Node there and what its there for.

Assuming you just wanted to move you character without any other interaction:
Just remove or comment the $Pivot line:

```
if direction != Vector3.ZERO:
    direction = direction.normalized()
    $Pivot.look_at(translation + direction, Vector3.UP) <-- This line
```

This should resolve your error and allow you to start the scene.

All it does is rotating the Pivot node into the direction you are moving. Without seeing the scene tree you copied the script from I can just assume it was used to rotate a crosshair or something similar into move direction.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was tearing my hear out with this.

Comment: No problem at all. If your problem is solved, consider setting this as correct answer, so people can se it is already resolved.